# Can't figure out why is ArrayList of objects not sorted properly

Tags: java

I'm working on an exchange sort for an ArrayList of objects so that it can be sorted ascending depending on the value in the object. When I compile it, everything works great until the last element is not sorted properly. I suspect that the problem is with the iterator. I tried many combinations but it won't sort properly. Also, I can't use sort() or any prebuilt libraries. I'd appreciate any guidance!

```
void sortAndDisplay (ArrayList<Car> cars) {

    Car temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size() -1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < cars.size(); j++ ) {
            if (((cars.get(i).getMake()).compareToIgnoreCase(cars.get(j).getMake()) > 0)) {
                temp = cars.get(i);
                cars.set(i, cars.get(j));
                cars.set(j, temp);
            }


        }
    }


      for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++) { 
          System.out.print(cars.get(i)+"\n\n");

      }


}
```

The Car class:

```
public class Car {
String make;
String model;


public Car (String make,
            String model)   {

    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;

}

public String getMake() {
    return make;

}
```

The method I used to read the values from the file:

```
ArrayList<Car> readCars(FileReader file) throws Exception  {
    String arr[] = {};
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader scan = new BufferedReader(file);
    ArrayList<Car> carsArr = new ArrayList<Car>();

    while ((line = scan.readLine()) != null) {
        arr = line.split(","); 
        Car car = new Car(arr[0], arr[1]);
        carsArr.add(car);
    }
    System.out.println("The file was read.");
    return carsArr;

}
```

Comment: I don't see an iterator here anywhere. What does "not sorted properly" mean, exactly? Have you stepped through in detail? Try putting `System.out.println(cars)` in your loop body.

Comment: There are multiple solutions for sorting a list in Java.  Why do you need swaping objects ?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I meant in the for loops. I described what "not sorted properly" means in the description - the last value printed out is out of sort. Meaning, everything is sorted properly except for the last value.

Comment: @fuat It's for a project for school. We have to implement the sorting algorithm by hand

Comment: `cars.size() -1` skips the last element.

Comment: If so follow this guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377448/how-to-do-sorting-in-array-list-without-using-collections-in-java

Comment: What is your output? Does your Car class have a toString() method?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes it does, an override

Answer (score 1):

java has sorting built in:

```
void sortAndDisplay (List<Car> cars) {
    cars.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getMake));
    System.out.println(cars.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n\n")));
}
```

Comment: I wish I could use it, but for the purpose of this project I'm not allowed to

Answer (score 0):

I created the file `x.txt` with the following data:

```
WERTfgd, bmw
ETRHFDdfgsdf, bmw
ewrd, bmw
HTfgdfgs, bmw
dDSFSfgd, bmw
ter, bmw
jhvbn, bmw
Frqw, bmw
```

I copied your code literally by adding `getMake()` into this `System.out.print (cars.get (i) .getMake () + "\ n \ n");` in order to get the wanted output...

### Output

```
dDSFSfgd

ETRHFDdfgsdf

ewrd

Frqw

HTfgdfgs

jhvbn

ter

WERTfgd
```

Which is correct, so I can't figure out what's your problem.

**Maybe you are not sure how the method `compareToIgnoreCase()` works?**

Comment: I just did this and now the bottom 2 items are out of sort :(

Comment: I edited my post with the Car class. Thank you for help!

Comment: If that helps, I just realized in the initial cars ArrayList fed to the method, the element that's being mis-sorted is the one with index = 0.

Comment: Can you show us how did you create the `ArrayList<Car>` that you passed to the method?

Comment: By the way change this `System.out.print(cars.get(i)+"\n\n");` into this `System.out.print(cars.get(i).getMake()+"\n\n");`, it will be better.

Comment: The attribute `make` is a numeric, alphanumeric, or alphabetic string? It can contain numbers?

Comment: Both attributes in the class are Strings

Comment: make only contains alphabetic strings at this moment  :(

Comment: Thank you for your help Alberto. I'm still having the same problem. In other words, let's say I want the output to be printed in this order: Audi, BMW, Chevrolet, Mazda, and I'm getting BMW, Chevrolet, Mazda, Audi. The element that gets pushed to the far back of the list is the element with an index of 0 in the initial array fed to the method. I understand what you're saying and thank you for your help, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: If you want, put your file so I can reproduce exactly the whole situation.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code with short example list and it worked. Could you give a failing example input with corresponding output?

BTW I recommend adding a `toString()` method to the `Car` class. For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "<Car<" + make + "><" + model + ">>";
}
```

With that printing the list of cars can be done like:

```
System.out.println(cars);
```